# How can SerialPort.set_ReadTimeout throw IOException { NativeErrorCode = ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED }?

Tags: .net, winapi, error-handling, serial-port

After sending a message out a `SerialPort` to a device, in preparation to read back its response, I tried setting the `ReadTimeout` and got back a rather oddball error:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  Message="The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.\r\n"
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
       at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError()
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
```

There are no other threads accessing the `SerialPort`, and no event handlers registered with it (which I hope would rule out interference from the implicit thread behind the port).

In any case, though, it just seems weird to me: how can `SetCommTimeouts` fail with `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`?

Comment: This has to come out of the device driver.  The USB ones are hopelessly shoddy.  Throw it away, get another one.

Comment: @Hans This is actually a serial port on the mainboard, not some USB dongle.